# How to find Global Clustering Coefficient of graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, social-networking, web-analytics

I start learning network analysis & its metrics calculation from last week. Don't have enough knowledge. Can anyone check this ?

The formula of finding the global clustering co-efficient is,

```
C = (3 * Number of Triangles) / (Number of connected triples of vertices)
```

I calculate the global clustering co-efficient as,

```
Number of Triangles = 2 
(as there are 2 directly connected triangles in the graph i-e Node4->Node5->Node6 and Node1->Node3->Node4)

Number of connected triples of vertices = 4 
(as Node1, Node2, Node3 & Node6 have three vertices connected)

 C = (3 * 2) / 4 = 1.5
```

I don't know I do it correctly or not. Can anyone check this ? or correct me If I am wrong

[image]

Comment: "connected triples" actually means "groups of three vertices connected by at least 2 edges". For instance, (1,4,6) is a connected triple.

Comment: @VincentLabatut Thanks. The vertices 1, 4 & 6 connects the 3 edges. But why not the vertices 2 & 3  ? They also connected with 3 edges.

Comment: Well, (1,3,7) and (1,2,7) are both connected triples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator must count all triples with 2 or 3 edges.
So, the the given graph we have the following triples:
5-4-6
6-5-4, 6-4-2, 6-5-2
4-6-1, 4-5-1, 4-6-3, 4-5-3, 4-1-3, 4-6-5
1-4-3, 1-3-2, 1-4-2
3-4-1, 3-1-7, 3-4-7
7-3-2
2-7-1, 2-1-6, 2-7-6
This gives a total of 20 triples, so the gcc is 2*3/20 = 0.3.

This algorithm is implemented in python's networkx package. The code for this example is:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([(5,6), (5,4), (4,6), (4,1), (4,3), (3,1), (3,7), (7,2), (1,2), (6,2)])
print(nx.transitivity(g))
```